# How to change one HTML file to another without changing link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html file(a webpage). I want when I press a button on it, the page should be replaced by another html file (with its own css, javascript functions etc) without being redirected to some other link.

For example, if link in first case is abc.com/def it should be same after too.

Using this code, I am able to change webpage look, but not getting how to change look (and also manage to load css and js functions) from another file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.write("THIS IS NEW TEXT")
        },
        false);
</script>
```

Comment: In other words, you want to **dynamically change the content of a webpage**. I'd suggest you read about this topic a bit to decide which technology has the features more appropriate to what you want to do. There are plenty of frameworks and techniques to do what you want, AJAX, AngularJS and many others can do what you want, each with their own perks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into frameworks like AngularJS, Specially Routing of Angular. They provide such features built-in for web applications. However, you can do it the hard way, using javascript, like you are doing it right now. Add CSS and change whole body HTML using javascript if you don't want to learn any new framework or libraries.

Comment: I don't want to use framework. I want to keep this page as light as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As discuss by others, you should use a Framework to do this..

But this is a complete solution you can inspire of:

```js
let layouts = {}
let current = null

// Display the new page by deleting current, and replacing by the good one
let displayLayout = (layout_id) => {
  let parentNode = current.parentNode
  parentNode.removeChild(current)
  current = layouts[layout_id]
  parentNode.appendChild(current)
  loadEvents(current)
}

// Load event for HTML DOM you just created 
let loadEvents = (layout_el) => {
  Array.from(layout_el.getElementsByClassName('go-to-layout')).forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      displayLayout(e.currentTarget.dataset.layout)
    })
  })
}
   
// On init I get all the existing layout, but you can build you own dictionary an other way.
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('layout')).forEach(l => {
  layouts[l.id] = l
  if (l.classList.contains('active')) {
    loadEvents(l)
    current = l
  }  
  else {
    l.parentNode.removeChild(l);
  }
})
```

```css
/* Global CSS */
body, html, .layout {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
* {
 color: #FFF
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
}

.nav, .page {
}
.nav {
  width: 150px;
  background: #555;
}

/* Special CSS for one layout */
#layout1 {
  background: red;
}
#layout2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="layout1" class="layout active">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="go-to-layout" data-layout="layout2">Page 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    This is page 1
  </div>
</div>

<div id="layout2" class="layout">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="go-to-layout" data-layout="layout1">Page 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    This is page 2
  </div>
  <style>.page { font-size: 2em }</style>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use **PJAX**,
Here's a [link](https://pjax.herokuapp.com/) for an example.